# Testing `isEqual` and `hash` methods

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

Here is pretty simple “bug scenario”: I have a perfectly working and covered with tests `MYPerson` class (with overwritten ‘isEqual’ and ‘hash’ methods). Then I decide to add a new property `job` of `MYJob` class, and forget to modify `isEqual:` and `hash` methods. The result is both these methods return `YES` when two `MYPerson` instances have different `job`s. Looks like the perfect bug to be caught by unit tests, but I have trouble writing such a test because of `OCMock` limitations - apparently both `isEqual` and `hash` methods can not be stubbed. And if I use actual `MYJob` objects in my tests I would be testing `MYJob` instead of `MYPerson` implementation, right?

Does anyone have a good solution or thoughts on this?

Comment: What about something like this:
`-(void)testShouldNotBeEqualOnDifferentJob
{
MYPerson *p1 = [MYPerson new];
*p1.job = [MYJob new];
MYPerson *p2 = [MYPerson new];
XCTAssert([p1 isEqual:p2]);
}
`